# How to search a string in multiple files and return all file information (like `dir`) in powershell?

Tags: powershell

Similar to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153750/how-to-search-a-string-in-multiple-files-and-return-the-names-of-files-in-powers). However, what I want is output similar to what you get when you `ls` or `dir` the directory, so that I get the timestamps, size, etc.

I tried

`Get-ChildItem -recurse | Select-String -pattern "dummy" | group path | select lastwritetime,name`

but had no success. When typing above I get:

```
Name                                    lastwritetime
File1.txt                                              
File2.txt
```

and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
Get-ChildItem -r | Select-String "dummy" -list | ls
```

Comment: Perfect! It even divides it by which directory it's in! You da bomb