# How to copy files based on their name in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying select files form a large directory contains certain numbers. Right now I have this.. it is copy all files in the directory.. It should be a simple little script.. however it's driving me nuts..

```
$files=Get-Content nametofind.txt
ForEach($file in $files){
Copy-Item "source\*.xml" -Destination "selected"  | where{$_.name -contains $($file)} 
}
```

What am I missing?

Extract of text file:

```
27216
27658
27716
27793
27961
27975
28599
28665
28931
29076
29077
29079
29080
29582
```

This goes on for ca. 2500 lines

And the file name that I am searching in is of the format

```
L_20211103_110803_8540_77498.xml
```

The last segment of the filename before the extension is the segment of interest.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search a string in multiple files and return the names of files in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153750/how-to-search-a-string-in-multiple-files-and-return-the-names-of-files-in-powers)

Comment: @Gimly Why is that a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep things simple by using wildcards in the `Copy-Item` command:

```
$files=Get-Content nametofind.txt
ForEach($file in $files){
  Copy-Item "source\*$file*.xml" -Destination "selected"
}
```

use the `-whatif` flag for the `Copy-Item` command to verify that what would occur is the desired behavior.